# How do I display an Integer to a Textview from the Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project where I store golf handicaps and update them when a user adds a score. I am saving the users handicap as an int in the users table and I'm trying to display the handicap in a text view.

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(user.getUid());
documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        int handicapV= parseInt("handicap");
        String y = String.valueOf(handicapV);
        GolfHandicap.setText(Integer.toString(handicapV));
    }
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "handicap"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
```

Comment: how are you parsing and int from a string "handicap"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `int handicapV= parseInt("handicap")` makes no sense, as the string `handicap` clearly isn't an integer.

You're probably looking for `int handicapV= parseInt(documentSnapshot.get("handicap"))`.